# Tabbed Pagination Help

Tags: html, css, pagination

I have built a simple pagination list and styled it using CSS. However, I've run into a problem. Because I want the list elements to be centred on the page, I've used a container `div` with `relative` positioning.

Here's an illustration that shows what I have at the moment, and what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Notice the seeming lack of a border on the current page number.

Here's the HTML markup for the list:

```
<div class="pagination-cont">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="disabled"><span>&lt; Previous</span></li>
        <li class="current"><span>1</span></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Page 2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Page 3">3</a></li>
        <li class="separator">&hellip;</li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Page 9">9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Page 10">10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Page 11">11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Next Page">Next &gt;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
div#content div.pagination-cont {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #d1d1d3;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    background-color: #e4e4e6;
}
    div#content div.pagination-cont ul.pagination {
        clear: left;
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        text-align: center;
    }
        div#content ul.pagination li {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: relative;
            right: 50%;
            font-size: 110%;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
            div#content ul.pagination li.disabled span,
            div#content ul.pagination li.separator {
                color: #bbb;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #f2f2f2;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                display: block;
            }
            div#content ul.pagination li.separator {
                border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d3
            }
            div#content ul.pagination li a {
                display: block;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                color: #004276;
                text-decoration: none;
                border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d3;
                margin-bottom: 1px
            }
                div#content ul.pagination li.current span {
                    display: block;
                    padding: 10px 20px;
                    border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d3;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    color: #999;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d1d3
                }
```

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: pardon, what is the difference between both images??, both are same

Comment: @diEcho - see sentence underneath image: 'Notice the seeming lack of a border on the current page number.' (i.e. on the "What I'd like to achieve" image)...

Comment: got it now. Please  see the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it, just remove "overflow:hidden" from "div.pagination-cont" (that is keeping the selected item from shifting to the top) and add "top:-1px; position:relative;" to: "ul.pagination li.current span", that should do the trick.

You can see it as http://jsfiddle.net/LGwDV/

Answer (score 0):

remove the

```
border-top: 1px solid #D1D1D3;
```

from

**div#content div.pagination-cont**

and write here

```
div#content ul.pagination li {
            border-top: 1px solid #d1d1d3;
        }
```

and also write one line in

```
div#content ul.pagination li.current {
                    border-top: medium none;                   
                }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5tjqv/)